# Values bigger than 0 being shown below the 0 axis on a Line and Stacked Column Chart on PowerBI

Tags: powerbi

I have the following problem:

[image]

The line values is bigger then 0, but all the columns is smaller then 0, it's good so far, the problem is:

The line must be above the 0 axis, because it is bigger then 0, I think it's logical...

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the Format settings, there should be an option under the Y-Axis section called **Align zeros**.

Switch this on and the line should be above the axis.